# Quorum Nodes not syncing

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum

I have 5 nodes with quite different block numbers( one is stuck at 201504, another at 280432 and so on) , they don't seem to be syncing. No particular error in Quorum Logs as well. Any transaction going in ends up in the pending queue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What consensus mechanism is being used?

Comment: Could you please provide more info or close this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please provide the consensus mechanism you are using.

In case it is raft please provide the output of `raft.cluster`

In case `raft.cluster` returns null you have to delete some internal file.

Comment: I hope this helped you.